# Error when create Sql job to remove server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have problem when I add sql job from c# code to MSSql server.
If I set serverInstance as domain name for exmaple: "S2n18P9s7" job created is done, but if I use ip server adress like "10.1.1.202" to connection i get expection:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Apply to target server failed for Job 'Job1'.  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The specified @server_name ('10.1.1.202') does not exist.
```

Code used to created task:

```
Server server = null;
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection sc = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection("10.1.1.202,1433", "REMOVED", "REMOVED");
server = new Server(sc);
server.LoginMode = ServerLoginMode.Normal;

Job job = null;
JobServer jobServer = server.JobServer;
JobSchedule schedule = null;

schedule = new JobSchedule(jobServer, String.Format("task1"));
schedule.FrequencyTypes = FrequencyTypes.OneTime;
schedule.ActiveStartDate = DateTime.Now;
schedule.ActiveStartTimeOfDay = new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0);
schedule.Create();

job = new Job(jobServer, "job1");
job.DeleteLevel = CompletionAction.OnSuccess;
job.Create();
job.AddSharedSchedule(schedule.ID);
job.ApplyToTargetServer(server.Name);
```

Comment: It is probably your network that you don' have control.  You network probably using Group Policy and requires to get PC name through the Password Server.  To get an IP address you require a route with a mask and the IP routing isn't working (or setup correctly).  You an verify by going to cmd.exe window and typing >Ping IP (or computer name) and verify the computer name returns a good result while the IP address fails.

Comment: I check ping with the IP address and compter name and both was correct.

Comment: Is SQL Server on a remote PC? Does Pin work from remote PC?